# How can we pass value of a variable in mentio-template-url

Tags: angularjs

I want to append basePath value in mentio-template-url of **mentio-menu**. But for the following code i am getting mentio-template-url value as '{{basePath}}template/product-mentions.tpl', basePath is not replace with its value.

```
              <mentio-menu
                        mentio-for="'theTextArea'"
                        mentio-trigger-char="'#'"
                        mentio-items="products"
                        mentio-template-url="{{basePath}}template/product-mentions.tpl"
                        mentio-search="searchProducts(term)"
                        mentio-select="getProductTextRaw(item)"
                        class="mentio-element-dropdown">                                
              </mentio-menu>
```

Comment: [linked github issue](https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io/issues/93)